# UI-Bootstrap Datepicker in ng-grid not working with enableCellEditOnFocus=true

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

I know how to have a working UI-Bootstrap-Datepicker inside an ng-grid cell's editableCellTemplate.

My Question:
It does not work anymore when I replace the enableCellEdit=true option with enableCellEditOnFocus=true (single-click on cell to edit). Does anyone have an Idea why it breaks and how to fix that?

```
var editableCellTemplateUsingDatePicker = '<input ng-class="\'colt\' col.index" datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" datepicker-append-to-body=true is-open="isOpen" ng-model="COL_FIELD" my-input="COL_FIELD"/>';

$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    //enableCellEdit: true,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
    enableCellSelection: true,
    enableRowSelection: false,
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'name',
      displayName: 'Name'
    }, {
      field:'dateOfBirth', 
      displayName:'Date of Birth', 
      editableCellTemplate: editableCellTemplateUsingDatePicker,
      cellFilter: 'date:"dd.MM.yyyy"',
    }]
    };
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kh0U7t3povAtfiHK7evf?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I found another way to get to the desired behaviour of single-click edit with the ui-bootstrap datepicker.

You can add ng-click="editCell()" to your custom cellTemplate to enter edit-mode through single-click of the cell. Here the working setup:

```
var cellTemplateEditOnClick = '<div class="ngCellText" ng-click="editCell()" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>{{row.getProperty(col.field) CUSTOM_FILTER}}</span></div>';

$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    enableCellEdit: true,
    enableCellSelection: true,
    enableRowSelection: false,
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'name',
      displayName: 'Name',
      cellTemplate: cellTemplateEditOnClick.replace('CUSTOM_FILTER', '')
    }, {
      field:'dateOfBirth', 
      displayName:'Date of Birth', 
      editableCellTemplate: editableCellTemplateUsingDatePicker,
      cellTemplate: cellTemplateEditOnClick.replace('CUSTOM_FILTER', '| date:"dd.MM.yyyy"')
    }]
    };
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tET2tT?p=preview)